# how to differentiate(using bgColor) edit cell only in ng-grid?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I have small clarification in Angularjs ng-grid .

How to differentiate the edit-cell and non-edit-cell in ng-grid ?

using bgColor's

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only custom the cellTemplate and add an CSS class to control it.

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText editable"> ... </div>'
```

Replace each cell individually or you can replace all the editable template.